# Web Part to Show Libraries and Contents?

Tags: web-part, content-query-web-part

Is it possible from the MOSS 2007 OOTB web parts with no custom code of any sort to create a view of all document libraries on a given site expanded to show all folders and documents within it?

Table of Contents will give you the libraries and CQWP will give you the documents but I'm looking for a combination of these I guess.

I pretty sure it's not possible OOTB but thought I would ask this here just in case.

Considering a DVWP to deliver the functionality but could save time if we can do this OOTB.

**NOTE TO SELF** - Stop end users from using document libraries as folders!

Answer (score 3):

A DVWP is going to be the way to go.  When you set to DataSourceMode="CrossList", you can get at all of the items in lists that meet the criteria you set.  Performance is usually not a problem, in my experience, unless you're dealing with multiple "large lists", which you say above isn't the case.

Once you get the hang of doing a DVWP with CrossList mode, you won't care so much about where the items are.

Comment: How might I look to render the heirarchy of libs folders and docs using a CrossList data source?

Comment: It depends on what you want it to look like.  I'd just do it in the DVWP with XSL.

Comment: I know the SPDataSource (default DS of a DVWP) has a ListOfLists mode. I haven't used this mode myself but this could help with one half of the equation? Maybe a CrossList to get all the items joined with a ListOfLists...just a theory

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spdatasource.datasourcemode.aspx

Comment: ListofLists is great for just getting at the lists themselves.  Since Charles is looking to show all Document Libraries AND their folders and documents, I think CrossList is the way to go and then handle the display across the Document Libraries with the XSL.  The ddwrt:NameChanged function will help greatly with this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. No it is not possible by OOTB web parts.

Comment: it probably wouldnt perform very well either depending on number of items and doclibs

Comment: It will be fine as each library has about 3 documents...See my note to self!